# Android Playscape Analytics error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

I have problem with Playscape sdk in unity. When trying to run Report.Instance.ReportLevelStarted application crashes on Android.

I'm using

```
Report.Instance.ReportLevelStarted (level, new Dictionary<string, double> (){ { "level ID",Application.loadedLevel } });
```

where level is a string name of the level. Did anyone had similar problem.

Comment: Which Playscape SDK version do you use? Could you provide a crash log?

Comment: I have sdk version 1.6. Here is crash log [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/otvafr4ckatiqi4/logSteampunkerCrash.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Could you update SDK to the latest one and check it?

Comment: Hello, after updating to version 1.17 the error is still the same.